# Sybase 8 to Sybase 16 migration in Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10, sybase

Currently we are using Sybase 16 db in our project. But there are few Sybase 8 db's (that clients are using in market) that needs to converted to Sybase 16 for any patch testing. I used to use the below query to migrate/convert Sybase 8 to Sybase 16 in **Windows 7 OS**

```
dbunload -c "UID=DBuserid; PWD= DBpwd; DBF=c:\PathOfSybase8dbToBeConverted\xxxSybase8.db;DBKEY=encryption key" -an c:\PathOfSybase16ConvertedDB\xxxSybase16.db
```

The above query used to work perfectly fine in Windows 7 OS and Sybase 8 db was getting migrated/converted Sybase 10 db without any hassle.

Recently, we migrated to **Windows 10 OS**. I have the same set up of Sybase 8 and 16 db's as it was in Windows 7 OS.

But when I run the above dbunload query, the query stops at some point, pointing to a table of my db as shown below

```
Adaptive Server Anywhere Unload Utility Version 8.0.2.3601
Unloading "DBA"."OneOfTheTableInMyDb" into OneOfTheTableInMyDb (relative to server)
```

Am I missing some setting in Windows 10 OS to run the query successfully? Any immediate help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are talking about Sybase ASA(Adaptive Server Anywhere).

Comment: Yes. Both sybase 8 (SQL Anywhere 8) and sybase (SQL Anywhere 16)16 are standalone dbs used in our project